# Matching correctly two same polygons that come from different shapefiles

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, topojson

I am trying to match two polygons that come from two different shapefiles, The one with the border (black line, MULTILINESTRING) and the one with blue color (multiple polygons) in the picture.

[image: see here]

This is the data for the border (black line)

| geometry | dep |
| --- | --- |
| MULTILINESTRING(((588969.0564105485.... | 92 |

And this is a snippet of my table with the blue polygons (there is 6256 polygons, so 6256 lines in this table)

| geometry | dep | top |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POLYGON ((598148.793 2438627.534, 598704.094 2.. | 92 | Ilotés |
| POLYGON ((599396.787 2437757.419, 599397.871 2... | 92 | Non ilotés |

How I can match them correctly, avoiding the exceeding areas that are outside the black border and the areas that are inside with holes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can polygonize the black line, union the polygonized and blue polygon dataframes, and select:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import unary_union, polygonize

blue = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/bluepolygons3.shp")
black = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/blackline.shp")

#Polygonize the black line
blackpoly = black.copy()
blackpoly.geometry = blackpoly.apply(lambda x: polygonize(unary_union(x.geometry))[0], axis=1)

#Create id columns that can be used to select by after the union
blue["blueid"] = range(blue.shape[0])
blackpoly["blackid"] = range(blackpoly.shape[0])

#Union
unioned = gpd.overlay(df1=blue, df2=blackpoly, how="union")

#Filled in blue polygons have blueid NaN and blackid some integer. I leave them unchanged

#Blue polygons outside the black have a blueid, but NaN blackid. Should be dropped
unioned = unioned.loc[~(unioned["blueid"].notna() & unioned["blackid"].isna())]

#Holes in the original blue layer are filled in, which is unwanted.
#  Create a dataframe with the holes as polygons
holes = blue.dissolve() #Create one big blue polygon
holes["interiors"] = holes.apply(lambda x: [polygonize(ring)[0] for ring in x.geometry.interiors], axis=1) #Extract the holes as a list
holes = holes.explode("interiors")
holes = holes.set_geometry("interiors").set_crs(blue.crs)

unioned = gpd.overlay(unioned, holes, how="difference") #Erase the holes from the union

#Drop columns created in the union
unioned = unioned[[column for column in unioned.columns if column in blue.columns]]
unioned.to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/UNION5.shp")
```

[image]